# surface view onResume crashes app

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, onactivityresult, surfaceholder

I am working with voice recognition and surface view in my app and my app crashes  when I press home button and when I again launch the application from background it crashes...

Here is my concern ...
1) if I open camera in `onCreate()` method and closed camera on `onPause()` method and when I launch app from the back it crashed

2) if I put camera opening code `onResume()` only  then camera doesn't start after `onActivityResult()` because  it has conflicting  code.

3) if I put camera opening on code in both the `onCreate()` and `onResume()` app crashes because camera object is already occupied and then again asking for camera resource in `onResume()` lead to null pointer error.

how can I resolve this issue. any help will greatly appreciated.

logcat:

```
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at com.client.mirrorapp.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:43)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:554)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:693)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1762)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
06-20 14:54:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "crashes app" indicates that you should take a look at the Stacktrace and post it in your question.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer updated logcat error for 2 (second) condition..

Comment: Put your oncreate code to onresume metod
i think you have created surfaceview in oncreate that`s why it gives error in onresume method.
make surface view in onresume method.

Comment: @user1632209 please refer second codition in which I there is conflict code in onActivityResult and in onResume so apart from that any other thing ...

Comment: There are various examples of camera + SurfaceView in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  In particular, the TextureFromCameraActivity class has a comment at the top about managing the Camera and Surface objects in different stages of the app lifecycle.  (It can be tricky to get it just right.)